# Cohort analysis using python and mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, optimization, analysis

I've made function to keep tracking active users which have been using my app and see their progress. Actually, I've made function in order to implement Cohort analysis of my users!

My idea was (Cohort analysis) to select time period (e.g 01/Oct/2012 up to 01/Oct/2013), take all users that used app first month in my case ( 01/Oct/2012 up to 01/Nov/2012), then tacking their progress in rest of selected months!(I mean "progress", if they used app next month, if they make activities)

So, I made function to do that job, but it's too too slow... Here is my function:

```
def query(self):
    start = fields['start'].value
    end = fields['end'].value
    start_month, start_year = start.month, start.year
    end_month, end_year = end.month + 1, end.year + 1
    col = self.db[self.__collection__]
    # we only follow users that were in the first month and
    # we have to filter those activities by month
    users_funnel = []
    data = []
    for dt in rrule(MONTHLY, dtstart=start, until=end):
        query = {
            "activities": {
                "$exists": 1
            },
            "activities.started": {
                "$exists": 1,
                "$type": MONGODB_DATE_TYPE,
                "$gte": dt,
                "$lt": datetime(dt.year + dt.month / 12, (dt.month % 12) + 1, 1)
            }
        }

        if users_funnel:
            query['_id'] = {"$in": users_funnel}

        pipeline = [
            {'$project': {
                '_id': 1,
                'first_name': 1,
                'last_name': 1,
                'email': 1,
                'activities': 1
            }},
            {'$unwind': "$activities"},
            {"$match": query},
            {'$group': {
                '_id': {"y": {'$year': "$activities.started"},
                        "m": {'$month': "$activities.started"}},
                'users': {'$addToSet': "$_id"},
                'activities_count': {"$sum": 1},
                'users_data': {"$addToSet": {
                    "_id": "$_id",
                    "first_name": "$first_name",
                    "last_name": "$last_name"}}
            }},
            {"$sort": {
                "_id.y": 1,
                "_id.m": 1
            }}
        ]
        results = col.aggregate(pipeline)
        result = results.get("result", [])
        if result:
            data.append(result[0])
            users_funnel = result[0]['users']
    return data
```

Then I've got **Cohort analysis** graph like this [graph](http://cl.ly/image/0C2P3y1d1b38).

Problem is about that function that I've made is too slow. I need better solution!

any can help me to develop Cohort analysis function querying mongodb in python ???

Comment: What indexes do you have?

Comment: I have "_id" indexes!

Comment: At minimum, `[{'activities.started': 1}, {'activities.started': -1}]`

Comment: No man, I can't do it .. What is that ? Read my question, pls!